# AngularJS: $compile doesn't work inside a controller

Tags: angularjs, svg

I am trying to use `$compile` to create an element within a controller, and can't get it to work.

```
$scope.open_svg = function(){
    var sc = $scope.$new(true);
    sc.fill = "#0000ff";
    var t = '<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" '+
            'xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> ' +
            '<rect ng-attr-x="10" y="10" height="100" width="100" ' +
            'style="stroke:#ff0000; fill:{{fill}}"/> ' +
            '</svg>';
    var svg = $compile(t)(sc);
    open("data:image/svg+xml,\n" + encodeURIComponent(svg[0].outerHTML));
}
```

This same code works fine within a directive. But as you can see, I am trying to open a new window so that the user can save the SVG, and I would like to do it without needing the code to be in a directive

Answer (score 2):

it works for me, as long as you execute the function ;) thats what you are probably missing.
How ever you really should consider moving this to a directive. having html code in your controllers is not recommended.

Comment: yeah you were almost right, I added the answer I found. As for not having HTML in code, I do not. The SVG's are rendered in a separate object and I just want to open it for saving. And this function just creates a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the code itself is almost fine, but since the $compile service is asynchronous, you should open the window AFTER the compilation is done. Otherwise the bindings are not resolved.

So just added a timeout,

```
    setTimeout(function(){
        var data_url = "data:image/svg+xml,\n" + encodeURIComponent(svg[0].outerHTML);
        $window.open(data_url, '_blank', 'toolbar=0,location=0,menubar=1');
    });
```

And it works.